# In Excel, how do I number the occurrences of items in a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of items that are repeated a varying number of times, but all occurrences are grouped together (don't have to worry about another "Apples" occurring 20 rows down).  I need to number each occurrence of the items using an array formula:

| Item | Occurrence |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | 1 |
| Apples | 2 |
| Apples | 3 |
| Apples | 4 |
| Oranges | 1 |
| Oranges | 2 |
| Oranges | 3 |
| Grapes | 1 |
| Grapes | 2 |
| Grapes | 3 |
| Grapes | 4 |

This sheet will be shared with others, and there could be dozens to hundreds of different items, and there could be anywhere from 1 to hundreds of occurrences of each item.  I need the solution to work on Windows/Mac/Web, so VBA isn't an option.
In Google Sheets, I found the following formula that works:

`=ArrayFormula(SORT(ROW(A2:A),SORT(ROW(A2:A),A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(A2:A,SORT(A2:A),0)-ROW()+1)`

I need to do the same thing in Excel, so I tried converting the ARRAYFORMULA to a LAMBDA since I've had good luck with them working cross-platform (though I'm very new to LAMBDA):

`=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(item,SORT(ROW(item),SORT(ROW(item),item,1),1)-MATCH(item,SORT(item),0)-ROW()+1))`

But this formula gives me an error in Google Sheets:

> "Function SORT parameter 2 expects number values. But 'Apples' is a
> text and cannot be coerced to a number."

And this error in Excel:

> "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."

I'm having a hard time understanding how the formula I found for Google Sheets actually works, so troubleshooting its LAMBDA equivalent hasn't worked for me. Any ideas on how to number my occurrences in Excel, either by fixing what I have, or is there a better option?

**Added:**

@Mureinik answer wasn't correct since I specified this needs to be an array formula, but I tried including his suggestion in a LAMBDA (along with some code to figure out the last row in the column), and it works!

`=BYROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(item, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW(item)), INDIRECT("A"&ROW(item))) ))`

As a bonus, the same code works in Google Sheets, and seems more efficient that what I had. Thanks @Mureinik, I gave you the check for putting me on the right path!

Comment: Are you using Excel desktop or Excel online?

Comment: I'm using desktop, but the solution needs to work in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `countif` function to count the occurrences of the given cell all the way to the top of the column. Assuming that "items" is column A and that there's a header row in row 1, the formula for row `n` would be:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$An, $An)
```

E.g., for row 123, you'll need:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A123, $A123)
```

Once you have the first two cells in, you can drag the formula all the way to the bottom of the column and Excel should sort out the numbering for you.

Comment: ,,, nice one +10 ☺

Answer (score 1):

@Mureinik answer wasn't correct since I specified this needs to be an array formula, but I tried including his suggestion in a LAMBDA (along with some code to figure out the last row in the column), and it works!

`=BYROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(item, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW(item)), INDIRECT("A"&ROW(item))) ))`

As a bonus, the same code works in Google Sheets, and seems more efficient that what I had.  Thanks @Mureinik for putting me on the right path!